# how to import data from HTML Button from a server

Tags: javascript, python, java, html, web-hosting

I am working on a project where I need to import data from My website i.e when someone clicks a button then a string should be generated and I should import that string to a python script running on windows on a client-side. For this purpose Ive used Flask-Python but the problem is that In flask we need to create a template folder in the project folder where the python script is saved.
but in my scenario, I need to run python script on windows and the template folder should be placed on the website page as I need to run HTML file on the webserver and import data from that file. I am facing this problem for a long time please someone help me.

Comment: I am a bit confused. I think there are 3 components to your application - a website server that is serving HTML (you mentioned using flask), the website client view (which will be your rendered template) and finally an independent python script running on the client side? (note that in the question I have asked, the client side python script and the flask webserver are not the same application and may not be on the same machine) This is a very different scenario than what the answer is solving, which assumes that the python script and the flask webserver are the same app on the same machine

Comment: I think a bit more detail about the structure of the application, and potential solutions you have tried might help

Answer (score 1):

You can send the string to your route in flask.
for example if you set your port in flask to `5000` so when you run it you can see in terminal the link to localhost lets say it looks like this `http://195.128.1.18:5000/` and your route in flask looks like this :

```py
@app.route('/')
def test():
    str = request.args.get('mystring', None)
    return str
```

and what it does it's basically shows the string you sent from  html.
And your html code to send the data looks like this :

```html
<body>
  <form target="_blank" action="http://195.128.1.18:5000/">
       Your String you want to send<input type="text" name="mystring">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I was a bit confused by the question, for some reason I feel that the OP is asking about a python script running client side independent from the flask webserver (which is server side). Your answer does seem to be the solution if this is not the case (the python script in question is the same as the flask webserver)